# Linking highcharts text renderer to javascript function

Tags: highcharts

I would like to add a text link in my chart that will execute a javascript function.
However, as you can see in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/phattanapon/6pQeU/1/), it looks like text renderer only accepts a URL link.
I notice that a credit can link to a javascript just fine and currently I'm using this as a workaround. 
Is this possible to achieve using text renderer?

```
chart.renderer.text('<a href="javascript:alert(1)">Text renderer javascript link</a>', 120, 60)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `renderer.text` method creates an `svg` element and only supports a subset of HTML tags.  Also, adding a javascript handler in the `href` is rather dated.  So, provide the handler using jquery's [click binding](http://api.jquery.com/click/).

```
function(chart) { // on complete
    var elem = chart.renderer.text('Text renderer javascript link', 120, 60)
        .css({
            color: '#4572A7',
            fontSize: '16px',
            cursor: 'pointer' // make it look clickable
        }); // save the element
    elem.add(); // add it 
    $(elem.element).click(function(){
       alert('hi'); 
    }); //bind a handler 
});
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/larsenmtl/6pQeU/2/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mark's construction or simpler:

```
chart.renderer.text('Text renderer javascript link', 120, 60)
    .css({
        color: '#4572A7',
        fontSize: '16px',
        cursor: 'pointer' // make it look clickable
    }).add().on('click',function(){
          alert('aaa');
    });
```